# Remap Keypad Ins/0 key to Right Arrow Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

The title pretty much covers it... What's the simplest way to do this? I'm currently flipping through the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us file, but there are a million different section, seemingly for different keyboard layouts or options, under that single file... I have no idea where to go to simply change my Ins/0 on Numpad so that it causes a right-arrow event, instead... (My right arrow key is broken).

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has worked for me in 16.04 and believe it should be similar. 
First of all, why don't you just use the keypad with Num Lock off and use the 4 key as a right arrow?
Anyway, if you want to remap the ins/0 key, you need to do this in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/keypad`. In there, edit the line

`key  <KP0> {  [  KP_Insert,   KP_0    ]   };`

to

`key  <KP0> {  [  KP_Insert,   Left    ]   };`

This will make this work as left with Numlock off
or

`key  <KP0> {  [  Left,    KP_0    ]   };`

to work with Numlock on. (Quite self explanatory).

Hope this helps